# Using Typescript in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to create a context in a React project using TypeScript. It's my first time with TypeScript and i'm getting an error. I tried to create some interfaces to solve the problem but I'm couldn't find a way to go around this.

Here's my context file:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, ChangeEvent } from 'react';

interface ITransaction {
  name: string;
  amount: string;
}

interface ITransactions {
  transactionsList: ITransaction[]
}

export const TransactionsContext = createContext({})

export const TransactionsContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState<ITransactions[]>([])
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<ITransaction>({
    name: '',
    amount: ''
  })

  const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target

    setInputs({...inputs, [name]: value })
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    setTransactions([...transactions, inputs]) <-- Error here
  }

  return (
    <TransactionsContext.Provider value={transactions}>
        {children}
    </TransactionsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

The error that I'm getting

```
Argument of type '(ITransaction | ITransactions)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<ITransactions[]>'.
  Type '(ITransaction | ITransactions)[]' is not assignable to type 'ITransactions[]'.
    Type 'ITransaction | ITransactions' is not assignable to type 'ITransactions'.
      Property 'transactionsList' is missing in type 'ITransaction' but required in type 'ITransactions'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `transactions` is of type `ITransactions[]` which means it is expecting value in this form:

```
[
{transactionsList:{name:'',amount:''}},
{transactionsList:{name:'',amount:''}},
{transactionsList:{name:'',amount:''}}
]
```

Now here     `setTransactions([...transactions, inputs]) <-- Error here` when you are updating state you trying to put only the object `{name:'',amount:''}` in the array but not
`{transactionsList:{name:'',amount:''}` , and hence the error.

Try this:

```
setTransactions([...transactions,{transactionsList:inputs}])
```